# Why does Clang++ not compile code with <header> on Windows?

Tags: windows, clang++

Why does clang++ compile this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and do not want compile this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "FFFF\n";
    return 0;
}
???
```

command line:

> clang++ -c hello.cpp -emit-llvm -o hello.bc

too many errors emitted like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\xrefwrap:222:22:
note:
      expanded from macro '_CLASS_RESULT_OF_PMF_OPT_0X'
                        __thiscall, X2, X3, X4)
```

Windows 7 64, clang-3.2, llvm-3.2, VS2012

---

=====UPDATE=====

Command line (with -v):

```
clang++ -c hello.cpp -emit-llvm -o hello.bc -v
```

What I get:

```
clang version 3.2 (tags/RELEASE_32/final)
Target: i686-pc-win32
Thread model: posix
 "C:/llvm/clang/build/bin/Debug/clang++.exe" -cc1 -triple i686-pc-win32 -emit-ll
vm-bc -disable-free -main-file-name 321.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-
fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -target-cpu pentium4 -m
omit-leaf-frame-pointer -v -coverage-file "C:\llvm\3211.bc" -resource-dir "C:/
llvm/clang/build/bin/Debug\..\lib\clang\3.2" -fmodule-cache-path "C:\Users\
\kpdev\AppData\Local\Temp\clang-module-cache" -internal-isystem C:/llvm/clan
g/build/bin/Debug/../lib/clang/3.2/include -internal-isystem "C:\Program Files
(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include" -internal-isystem "C:\Program
 Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\\include" -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -ferro
r-limit 3 -fmessage-length 80 -mstackrealign -fms-extensions -fms-compatibility
-fmsc-version=1300 -fdelayed-template-parsing -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fobjc-default-
synthesize-properties -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -f
color-diagnostics -o "C:\llvm\3211.bc" -x c++ "C:\llvm\321.cpp"
clang -cc1 version 3.2 based upon LLVM 3.2svn default target i686-pc-win32
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...>search starts here:
 C:/llvm/clang/build/bin/Debug/../lib/clang/3.2/include
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\include
End of search list.
In file included from C:\llvm\321.cpp:1:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\inc
lude\iostream:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\inc
lude\istream:6:
```

...etc.

and then:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\type_traits:1072:
33: error:
      '_Ty' does not refer to a value
                _HAS_TRIVIAL_MOVE_CONSTRUCTOR(_Ty)
                                              ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\type_traits:52:38
: note:
      expanded from macro '_HAS_TRIVIAL_MOVE_CONSTRUCTOR'
                        && __has_trivial_move_constructor(_Ty)>
                                                          ^
```

...etc.

So... `-internal-isystem` point to wrong path. How to change it ?

Answer (score 1):

You have the include path configured incorrectly for clang.  This:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\xrefwrap
```

is a header file from the VS 2012 installation and has noting to do with clang (and is apparently incompatible with it).

Make sure your environment isn't set up for the VC++ compile. For example, make sure there's no `INCLUDE` environment variable that's set up for VC++.  There may be other env variables to make sure aren't inappropriately set for clang, too, such as `LIB`.

Comment: Thank you. But I cant find this environment variable. Where is it hide?

Comment: So if you do `set INCLUDE` from the command line does it say `Environment variable INCLUDE not defined` or something else?  If you're building from the command line (and not an IDE or something) using that command and there's no `INCLUDE` environment variable then I'm not sure why clang would be searching `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE`. But I don't have clang installed on my Windows machine, so I can't try it out or test at the moment. You might see if the `-v` option gives you any helpful information.

Comment: If I do `set INCLUDE` (or `set LIB`), it say `variables not defined`. Rezult of `-v` option in question update.